# How to append the contents to the file at the beginning using Java?

Tags: java, filewriter

I have used `Filewriter` class. But it will append at the end of the file. Can anyone tell me the method to append the contents to the file at the beginning without overwriting.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500522/how-to-prepend-to-a-file-add-at-the-top

Comment: that is prepend not append,duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537944/prepend-lines-to-file-in-java

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't, basically. That's not a Java limitation so much as a file system limitation - I can't remember ever seeing an API which allows this.

You'll need to create a *new* file, write your new data, then append the contents of the original file to it.