# How can I append a header to a CSV file I am writing out in R?

Tags: r

I am able to export a dataframe into CSV file but I need to append two lines of information before I do that. I don't write out the column names.

```
Trend data
110
```

Here, "Trend data" is just a text. And, 110 is the number of rows in the data frame I am writing out.

How can I append this information in the header of the csv file I am writing out in R?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to append it to the column names, or make a new 2 lines before the data?

Comment: I don't need the column names in the file I am writing out. I want to add two new lines before the data. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This ought to do it:

```
x <- 1:110

writeLines(c("Trend data","110"), "myfile.dat")
write.table(x, "myfile.dat", col.names=FALSE, row.names=FALSE, append=TRUE)
```

Looking at it from the Mac OS X terminal:

```
$ head myfile.dat
Trend data
110
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

Comment: Ahh, `writeLines`... that's what I needed.  After further review, mine won't work.  Very nice.

Comment: The poster's question actually made me remember the `append` argument :-) I keep forgetting many of the `write…` functions have that. There are times that comes in really handy.

Comment: Right.  I tried `rev(append(...` with no luck.  Is there a way to reverse `append`?  It prints the same result no matter which order you have the arguments listed.

Comment: I don't think so ([ref](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16128001/is-it-possible-to-append-to-the-first-line-of-an-exisiting-file)). At least I've not been able to find `base` or `stats` function that wraps the process.

Comment: I got something with `sink`.  See answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `write.table` and `sink`. The `sink` function diverts R output to a specified file, appending it to what's already in the file, if desired.

```
> x <- data.frame(x = letters[1:5])

> write.table("Trend Data\n110", row.names = FALSE, 
              col.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE, file = "my.csv")
> sink("my.csv", append = TRUE)
> x
> sink()

> write.table(readLines("my.csv"), row.names = FALSE,
              col.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)
Trend Data
110
  x
1 a
2 b
3 c
4 d
5 e
```